# Setting jar file in environmental variables

Tags: java, environment-variables

My jar file is available in E:\ So How to add jar file to environmental variables now?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: `So How to add jar file to environmental variables now?` ??

Comment: I assume he is talking about the class path but with 19 out of 19 questions without an accepted answer the OP hasn't learnt much so far.

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered many times before, but here goes:

You make the Java runtime aware of your JAR with the `-cp` option:

```
java -cp E:\yourjarfile.jar com.yourpackage.YourProgram
```

You can do the same via the `CLASSPATH` environment variable:

```
set CLASSPATH="E:\yourjarfile.jar;E:\yourotherjarfile.jar"
```

See [this Windows example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html).

Comment: `export CLASSPATH = "%classpath%;E:\yourjarfile.jar` on windows command line and `export CLASSPATH = "$(CLASSPATH);E:\yourjarfile.jar"` on linux

Comment: `set CLASSPATH` on Windows instead of `export` ? Anyway, yes--the above is true if you want to preserve previous incantations of CLASSPATH...

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for the negligence, its `set CLASSPATH` on windows. Thanks for the correction