# problem setting classpath of javamail?

Tags: java, classpath, jakarta-mail

I downloaded [java mail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) because i wanted to run the code that had header files :

`import javax.mail.*;`

`import javax.mail.internet.*`

But even after setting the class path i am unable to run that code.

The jar files included in java mail are :

1. mail.jar
2. dsn.jar
3. imap.jar
4. mailapi.jar
5. pop3.jar
6. smtp.jar

I edited my classpath variable and finally it was :

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\javamail-1.4.4\mail.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javamail-1.4.4\lib;.;**

The first jar file is in a seperate directory and the remaining jar files are in one directory.

If the class path is set wrong , then please tell the mistake. *(i have taken the correct directories)*

If there is no problem with the class path then what is the problem ?

Comment: Please specify full command how you call java

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify each single jar separately in classpath, specifying directory with jars won't work.

Comment: Yes ! thank you. Though i have been setting classpath but i don't know why we put **.;** (dot semicolon in the end). What is the reason ?

Comment: Dot (.) -- means the current location from where you run the application. Semicolon (;) is the path separator under Windows. Colon (:) is the path separator under Linux/Unix.

Comment: @ 01es what does it actually mean here ? what if omit the dot ?

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards can be used as part of the classpath. Pls refer [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You make the Java runtime aware of your JAR with the `-cp` option:

```
java -cp E:\yourjarfile.jar com.yourpackage.YourProgram
```

You can do the same via the `CLASSPATH` environment variable:

```
set CLASSPATH="E:\yourjarfile.jar;E:\yourotherjarfile.jar"
```

See [this Windows example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html).

Also, this was [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518309/setting-jar-file-in-environmental-variables/6518376#6518376).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have a directory "**C:\Users\excont\Desktop\Send Mail**" which contains all jar files & Java class.

so just follow this step. You will definitely get the result

C:\Users\excont\Desktop\Send Mail>**set CLASSPATH=dsn.jar;imap.jar;mailapi.jar;pop3.jar;smtp.jar;.;**

C:\Users\excont\Desktop\Send Mail>**javac SendMail.java**

C:\Users\excont\Desktop\Send Mail>**java SendMail**

Hope I could help you or anyone searching for the same.